# Get td value inside tr from table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
$(this).closest('tr').html();
```

with that code i get the full html layout of my td's in the tr.
But how can i get an specefic value in that td?

Comment: Value of what? Which `td`? Show your markup.

Comment: `$(this).closest('tr > td').html();`? Or if it is a specific index you could do `$(this).closest('tr > td:eq(1)').html();` meaning the second one.

Comment: `$(this).closest('td').html();`

Comment: Use a data attribute to distinguish one cell from another and target it directly.

Comment: Folks, it is really nasty to down vote newcomers because they may be asking simple or poorly phrased questions -- especially when you do so without providing them with a helpful comment or guidance.  Reserve your down votes for folks who should know better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('td').text()
```

Will return the contents of the tds, given that this is in the row.